# writing mock test case for log methods

Tags: java, logging, methods, mockito, void

```
public void logTimeTaken(String label, long estimatedTime, int size, boolean isDebug) 
{
    String out = label + " took " + 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(estimatedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
        + " milliseconds for " + size + " events!";

    if (isDebug) {
        logger.debug(out);
    } else {
        logger.info(out);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to write mockit here any one know help me in this..
test code here..

```
@Mock
EventUtility event;

@Test
public void getLogTimeTaken_checkBooleanTrue() {

    doNothing().when(event).logTimeTaken("Corner Stone", 1000, 100, true);

    eventUtil.logTimeTaken("Corner Stone", 1000, 100, true);

    verify(event).logTimeTaken("Corner Stone", 1000, 100, true);
}
```

I test this code but i'm getting exception ,I don't know  it is correct way or not and below is the exception

> Exception ::Wanted but not invoked: event.logTimeTaken( "Corner
>   Stone",1000,100,true);
>   -> at com.wf.cornerstone.datacontrols.util.EventUtilityTest.getLogTimeTaken_checkBooleanTrue(EventUtilityTest.java:244)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
at com.wf.cornerstone.datacontrols.util.EventUtilityTest.getLogTimeTaken_checkBooleanTrue(EventUtilityTest.java:244)
```

can you help me this ..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the mock the code like

Comment: added my test code here kindly help me

Comment: How do you initialize "event", What class is this? Do you have any "setup" method? Can show it too?

Comment: In EventUtility class having logTimetaken() method I need to test this method.

Comment: Can you show us where `eventUtil` is being initialised?

Comment: just I test log methods in Logtimetaken() ,I don't know mockit complete pls help me

Comment: enventUtil is just reference like EventUtil eventUtil =new EventUtil();

Comment: And the class **EventUtil** does have a reference to the class **EventUtility**?

Comment: eventUtil is reference to EventUtility class

Comment: So you expect that event calls logTimeTaken when you make a call to eventUtil.logTimeTaken??

Comment: yes, i'm excepting my test case is pass without getting out object in logtimetaken

Comment: guys any one know please post your answers i'm unable to complete test ,nearly 1week left please guys.